# What's the best way to inform user about availability of more categories than what are visible on UI

Tags: user-behavior, many-options

Currently, we've 100+ categories on homepage. So many categories 'might' be creating information overload for the new user so we are planning to show the categories (around 30-40 in number) that are clicked more as compared to other categories. Remaining categories (that are not visible on UI on page load) will be shown only on search (search results will be in a drop down like Google autocomplete) or on click of a button to load all the categories. Here are my dilemmas:

1. How can we effectively communicate to the user that there are more categories so user should search or click on 'load all the categories' button? Here is the UI that we are planning for (at the end of the homepage):

   [image: too many categories on homepage]
2. What are the better UI + UX options to improve this?

PS: We have a search bar at the top of the homepage as well (above the categories).

Answer (score 2):

Although the search bar searches for categories, I think it feels like it "searches for anything". So there is no necessity to bring that relation in the UI.

My suggestion is that the Load more button stays just after the categories list, and the search stays in some distance. Also try to give the same height to the three columns so the Load more button (which might or not have the same width as the column) looks like it refers to the three columns.

Also think about including a Search button, if the magnifier is the button make it more obvious once the user has typed something.

[image]